# How to read a DC2Type array with doctrine and symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm setting up an advanced search for a jobboard and I need to find resumes by contract, knowing that a resume can have multiple contracts.

I have a form where you can choose which type of contract you are looking for (It's a ChoiceType::class with multiple => true)

In my table, my colomn contract :

[image]

In my Entity Resume :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $contract = [];

public function getContract(): ?array
{
    return $this->contract;
}

public function setContract(?array $contract): self
{
    $this->contract = $contract;

    return $this;
}
```

In my repository :

```
public function findByContract(array $contract)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->andWhere('r.contract IN (:cons)')
        ->setParameter('cons', $contract)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

In my controller :

```
public function index(Request $request, ResumeRepository $resumeRepository)
{
    $formSearch = $this->createForm(ResumeSearchFormType::class);
    $formSearch->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formSearch->isSubmitted() && $formSearch->isValid()) {
        $data = $formSearch->getData();

        $results = $resumeRepository->findByContract($data->getContract());
        var_dump($results); die;
```

This var_dump() returns an empty array.

I don't know how I can do to find resume by contract

Comment: You can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346152/what-is-dc2type-array-datatype-in-mysql

Comment: Hi marv255, I find the begin of the answer thnks to you, doing `->setParameter('cons', serialize($contract))`, but if the string is not exactly the same as in the db It's doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you find the solution but maybe I can help someone else!
I had the same issue, so I used LIKE instead of IN, and I used the setParameter differently.
Like this :

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
    ->andWhere('r.contract LIKE (:cons)')
    ->setParameter('cons', '%' .$contract. '%')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

If you want more information about it, check this: [What is DC2Type array datatype in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346152/what-is-dc2type-array-datatype-in-mysql)