# Add TINYINT to Doctrine SQL types

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dbal, symfony-4.4

Following Symfony doc, I tried to add `TINYINT` as entity column type.

So far it works well, but two problem remain...

1. Each time I want to perform a migration, Doctrine can't reconize `TINYINT` for the associated columns, and perform the migration queries again.
2. In form builders, by default `TINYINT` is reconized as `TextType` and not `NumberType`

Do you know what I'm missing to fix those two issues?

**`TinyintType.php`**

```php
use Doctrine\DBAL\ParameterType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

class TinyintType extends Type {
    const TINYINT='tinyint';

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return self::TINYINT;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $fieldDeclaration
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return $fieldDeclaration['unsigned'] === true ? 'TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED' : 'TINYINT(1)';
    }

    public function canRequireSQLConversion() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param $value
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return $value === null ? null : (int)$value;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     * @return int|mixed|null
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return $value === null ? null : (int)$value;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getBindingType() {
        return ParameterType::INTEGER;
    }
}
```

**`doctrine.yaml`**

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        server_version: '5.7'
        types:
            tinyint: 'App\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TinyintType'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11472344/231316), there might be an extra `mapping_types` for migrations that _might_ help Doctrine.

Comment: I tried this, but doctrine keep generating the same migration file as if the DB type hasn't changed @ChrisHaas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First issue:* From https://blog.vandenbrand.org/2015/06/25/creating-a-custom-doctrine-dbal-type-the-right-way/

> The solution is to add a comment to the field to store the metadata
> in. This seems to be missing in the docs but I’ve found some JIRA
> issue describing the feature. We have to change our column definition
> so the metadata of the type doesn’t get lost

So your **getSQLDeclaration** should be like this:

```
public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return 'TINYINT'.(!empty($fieldDeclaration['unsigned']) ? ' UNSIGNED' : '').' COMMENT \'(DC2Type:tinyint)\'';
}
```

*Second issue:* That's because, by default symfony forms uses text type (**symfony/form/FormBuilder.php::create**)

```
if (null === $type && null === $this->getDataClass()) {
    $type = 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType';
}
```

You should set your type explicitly if you want to set another type.

Comment: I can't personally confirm that the comment thing works, but I see that it exists in the codebase with an [actual method for parsing](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/c6d37b4c42aaa3c3ee175f05eca68056f4185646/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/AbstractSchemaManager.php#L1127), and there'd a [thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10689771/231316), so this seems like an official although undocumented way to do it!

Comment: I remember similar thing with array type indeed, I will try it out asap, but seems correct to me. Thanks

Comment: Worked, migration are detected just fine now. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

While the information in the accepted answer are ok, I missed a solution to copy&paste here, so here it is.

Type declaration:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\SmallIntType;

class TinyintType extends SmallIntType
{
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $column, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'TINYINT' . (!empty($column['unsigned']) ? ' UNSIGNED' : '');
    }


    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tinyint';
    }
}
```

And type registration somewhere in the initialization code:

```php
\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType('tinyint', TinyintType::class);
```